# resize image on Amazon S3 timthumb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, timthumb

i have created amazon S3 bucket for saving images. Earlier i was using timthumb to server thumbnail for images. Now with S3 using timthumb is not a good idea as images will be downloaded to EC2 and then to client. Should I upload two copied of images to S3 one original and one for thumbnail. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The best method would be to leverage the AWS service itself. Since you were using the timthumb plugin, the thumb generation would be the same. S3 can fire a lambda function on any event.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/walkthrough-s3-events-adminuser.html

There are AWS lambda code which can generate thumbnails based on configured values. The AWS Lambda console itself has some of them which you could tweak into a working system. The link to the console will not work unless you are logged in.

Disclaimer: I am a third party solution consultant and not directly working for AWS.